# how to serially off leds in an esp running mqtt

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, arduino-ide, mqtt

hi im using at tiny 85 to monitor dc switches and to serial print with this code
below to esp8266 with local broker to turn leds on and off but its only working through mqtt but not with physical switches which are connected to at tiny 85. please help this is my mqtt code

```
//////at tiny code///
#include <SendOnlySoftwareSerial.h>

SendOnlySoftwareSerial myserial (4);  // Tx pin

int sw1 = 0;
int sw2 = 1;
int sw3 = 2;
int sw4 = 3;

int sta1 = 0;
int sta2 = 0;
int sta3 = 0;
int sta4 = 0;

bool st1 = false;
bool st2 = false;
bool st3 = false;
bool st4 = false;
void setup () {
 
  myserial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(0, INPUT);
  pinMode(1, INPUT);
  pinMode(2, INPUT);
  pinMode(3, INPUT);
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
 
  }
void loop ()
{
  sta1 = digitalRead(sw1);
  sta2 = digitalRead(sw2);
  sta3 = digitalRead(sw3);
  sta4 = digitalRead(sw4);
  if (sta1 == HIGH && st1 == false){
    myserial.println("sw1 on");
    st1 = true;
    delay(1);
  }
    else if (sta1 == LOW && st1 == true){
      myserial.println("sw1 off");
      st1 = false;
      delay(1);
    }

   if (sta2 == HIGH && st2 == false){
    myserial.println("sw2 on");
    st2 = true;
    delay(1);
  }
    else if (sta2 == LOW && st2 == true){
      myserial.println("sw2 off");
       st2 = false;
      delay(1);
    }

   if (sta3 == HIGH && st3 == false){
    myserial.println("sw3 on");
     st3 = true;
    delay(1);
  }
    else if (sta3 == LOW &&  st3 == true){
      myserial.println("sw3 off");
       st3 = false;
      delay(1);
    }
   if (sta4 == HIGH &&  st4 == false){
    myserial.println("sw4 on");
    st4 = true;
    delay(1);
  }
    else if (sta4 == LOW&& st4 == true){
      myserial.println("sw4 off");
      st4 = false;
      delay(1);
    }
   
}
```

```
//////esp mqtt code///////
//ItKindaWorks - Creative Commons 2016
//github.com/ItKindaWorks
//
//Requires PubSubClient found here: https://github.com/knolleary/pubsubclient
//
//ESP8266 Simple MQTT light controller


#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

int LED3 = D2;
int LED4 = D4;
int LED2 = D3;
int LED1 = D5;

String data ;
// the number of the pushbutton pin

//EDIT THESE LINES TO MATCH YOUR SETUP

#define MQTT_SERVER "192.168.43.223"
const char* ssid = "kuro";
const char* password = "qwertyui";

//LED on ESP8266 GPIO2

char* lightTopic = "/test/light1";
char* lightTopic1 = "/test/light2";
char* lightTopic2 = "/test/light3";
char* lightTopic3 = "/test/light4";


WiFiClient wifiClient;
void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length);
PubSubClient client(MQTT_SERVER, 1883, callback, wifiClient);

void setup() {
  //initialize the light as an output and set to LOW (off)
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(LED3 , OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED4 , OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED1 , OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED2 , OUTPUT);
 
    delay(100);

    // We start by connecting to a WiFi network

    Serial.println();
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("Connecting to ");
    Serial.println(ssid);

    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(500);
        Serial.print(".");
    }

  
  if (Serial.available()>0) /* If data available at serial port, enter if loop */
  {
    data = Serial.readStringUntil('\n'); /* Read data present at serial port */
    /* Print string with \r\n */
    Serial.println(data); /* Print data received */
  }  
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("WiFi connected.");
    Serial.println("IP address: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
    
}



void loop(){
  //reconnect if connection is lost
  if (!client.connected() && WiFi.status() == 3) {reconnect();}

  //maintain MQTT connection
  client.loop();

  //MUST delay to allow ESP8266 WIFI functions to run
  delay(10); 
}


void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length)
{
  //convert topic to string to make it easier to work with
  String topicStr = topic; 

  //Print out some debugging info
  Serial.println("Callback update.");
  Serial.print("Topic: ");
  Serial.println(topicStr);

 if(topicStr.equals(lightTopic)||Serial.available()){

   if(payload[0] == '1' || data.equals ("sw1 on")){
      digitalWrite(LED1 , HIGH);
    }

    else if (payload[0] == '0'|| data.equals ("sw1 off")){
      digitalWrite(LED1 , LOW);
    }
 }
 if(topicStr.equals(lightTopic1)||Serial.available()){

   if(payload[0] == '1'|| data.equals ("sw2 on")){
      digitalWrite(LED2 , HIGH);
    }

    else if (payload[0] == '0'|| data.equals ("sw2 off")){
      digitalWrite(LED2 , LOW);
    }
 }
 if(topicStr.equals(lightTopic2)||Serial.available()){

   if(payload[0] == '1'|| data.equals ("sw3 on")){
      digitalWrite(LED3 , HIGH);
    }

    else if (payload[0] == '0'|| data.equals ("sw3 off")){
      digitalWrite(LED3 , LOW);
    }
 }
  if(topicStr.equals(lightTopic3)||Serial.available()){

   if(payload[0] == '1'|| data.equals ("sw4 on")){
      digitalWrite(LED4 , HIGH);
    }

    else if (payload[0] == '0'|| data.equals ("sw4 off")){
      digitalWrite(LED4 , LOW);
    }
  }
  
}






void reconnect() {

  //attempt to connect to the wifi if connection is lost
  if(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
    //debug printing
    Serial.print("Connecting to ");
    Serial.println(ssid);

    //loop while we wait for connection
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
      delay(500);
      Serial.print(".");
    }

    //print out some more debug once connected
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("WiFi connected");  
    Serial.println("IP address: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  }

  //make sure we are connected to WIFI before attemping to reconnect to MQTT
  if(WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED){
  // Loop until we're reconnected to the MQTT server
    while (!client.connected()) {
      Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");

      // Generate client name based on MAC address and last 8 bits of microsecond counter
      String clientName;
      clientName += "esp8266-";
      uint8_t mac[6];
      WiFi.macAddress(mac);
      clientName += macToStr(mac);

      //if connected, subscribe to the topic(s) we want to be notified about
      if (client.connect((char*) clientName.c_str())) {
        Serial.print("\tMTQQ Connected");
        client.subscribe(lightTopic);
        client.subscribe(lightTopic1);
        client.subscribe(lightTopic2);
        client.subscribe(lightTopic3);
   
        
      }

      //otherwise print failed for debugging
      else{Serial.println("\tFailed."); abort();}
    }
  }
}

//generate unique name from MAC addr
String macToStr(const uint8_t* mac){

  String result;

  for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
    result += String(mac[i], 16);

    if (i < 5){
      result += ':';
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should add some code to the ESP8266 that reads from serial and does something depending on what has been read?

Comment: shouldn't the code for reading Serial be in loop(), not in setup()?

Comment: Majenko is right, you just don't have any code, that would read and process serial input on the ESP (besides the bit in setup, which is only called once at startup), thus it will not react to serial data. The solution: Program the ESP to read the serial data and process it. Then you can write code, that reacts to serial data

Comment: hi thank you everyone, so i wrote another code to just print and blink an led, its printing fine but not turning the led on/off ```String command;
 int led = 3;
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600); 
    pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
    
}
 
void loop() {
    if(Serial.available()>0){
        command = Serial.readString();
        Serial.print(command);
         
        if(command.equals ('sw4 on')){
            digitalWrite(led , HIGH);
        }
        else if(command.equals ('sw4 off')){
            
            digitalWrite(led , LOW);
        }
        
    }
    
}```

Comment: ' is for char. use ". the text sent from atiny with print***ln*** ends with \r\n so it is not equal to "sw4 on".

Comment: thank you so much juraj that must be it now i got it working